# Setters are working but getters are not

Tags: java, android

I have created a user class that I collect the data in

```
public class Users {
 private String name;


 public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }
}
```

Then I take the text from the user this way

```
Users users=new Users();
String name=editTextmain.getText().toString();
users.setName(name);
```

After that I want to view the name in a toast 
so I do this

```
Users users=new Users();
Toast.makeText(this,users.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

the toast appears empty, any ideas?

Comment: You are creating a new Users.. You should use the same one

Comment: Class name is misleading. It only represent a *single* user, not multiple users, so it should be called `User`, not `Users`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing this

```
Users users=new Users();
```

You are creating new object each time which doesn't have value. So you need to make your model class **Singleton**

```
    public class Users {
     private String name;
     public static Users user;

     public static Users getInstance(){
        if(user == null)
           user = new Users();
        return user;
     }

     private Users(){

     }    

     public String getName() {
         return name;
     }

     public void setName(String name){
         this.name=name;
     }
 }
```

Now use this...

```
1. to set the name

Users.getInstance().setName("Your Name");

2. to get the name

Users.getInstance().getName();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new object before `Toast.makeText`

```
Users users=new Users();
Toast.makeText(this,users.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You'll have to use `users` initialized earlier here

```
Users users=new Users();
String name=editTextmain.getText().toString();
users.setName(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do this after some where in other method:

```
Users users=new Users();
```

you are declaring another users object and its data is empty...

you need to get the original user you declared/initiated before....

make sure the users is a class object and dont make shadows over it...

## Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ....{

  Button btnActTwo;
  ....
  Users users;
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a new, empty user for the toast:

```
Users users=new Users();
Toast.makeText(this,users.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You need to set the name to the user first:

```
Users users=new Users();
users.setName("your name here");
Toast.makeText(this,users.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

or do not create a new User and just use the previous one.

Comment: i get it , so how to get the old user that i created to another activity

Comment: Make your User parcelable and pass it via the intent, when launching your new Activity.